# Commit published twice: Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin'

Tags: git, version-control, merge, fast-forward

I forked from a repository (upstream), then do my changes locally and push to my repo (origin).

To add to this, I do most of my work at my console, and today I did some on the laptop.

I pushed to origin on my console, then `git fetch origin; git merge origin/master` on my laptop the next day.

What happened is that I took all the changes from the day before, committed them to my laptop, and pushed those back to origin. Now I have two sets of commits on my origin/master for the same work, once for the console, and once for the laptop.

I've read before that I should [publish once](http://sethrobertson.github.com/GitBestPractices/), and though I'm certainly not considering altering this pushed history, I do want to avoid this whenever a lapse occurs between workstations. The commit history looks confusing.

I thought the [`--no-ff`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) option on `git pull` looked promising, but most of the information I find for this topic is about keeping [local branches in sync](http://nathaniel.themccallums.org/2010/10/18/using-git-fast-forward-merging-to-keep-branches-in-sync/) as master is being developed on by others.

Comment: Why were the changes that you merged on your laptop not already committed? i.e. why were you able to commit again on your laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have work that was done in parallel (in terms of history) it's fine to merge. If you want linear history, use the `--rebase` option on the pull. Further, you can set your configuration so that pull does a rebase instead of a merge every time.